# Problem with RangeSlider second node is invisible

Tags: javafx, rangeslider

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqDCE.png)
[Actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLZrI.png)

My problem is that the second node of the RangeSlider turns invisible after i set seats.setShowTickLabels(true); to true.

It is still there because the lowValue cannot go beond the highValue.

Code:

```
    @FXML
    public RangeSlider seats = new RangeSlider();

    private static final int SEATS_MIN = 150;
    private static final int SEATS_MAX = 300;

    seats.setPrefWidth(500);

    seats.setMin(Airplane.getSEATS_MIN());
    seats.setMax(Airplane.getSEATS_MAX());

    seats.setLowValue(180);
    seats.setHighValue(260);


    seats.setShowTickLabels(true);
```

I have read through this: https://controlsfx.github.io/javadoc/11.0.3/org.controlsfx.controls/org/controlsfx/control/RangeSlider.html

And if added listeners to it:

```
seats.highValueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
        if (!oldValue.equals(newValue)) {
            highLabel.setText(String.valueOf(newValue));
        }
    }
});

seats.lowValueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
        if (!oldValue.equals(newValue)) {
            lowLabel.setText(String.valueOf(newValue));
        }
    }
});
```

Also im using maven and javafx 11.1.2 for my project. I apreciate every feedback (this is my first question), sorry for bad english :)

Comment: Create and post a [mre]

Comment: Without going too deep into the code, if `seats` is in your FXML file, then you shouldn't use `new RangeSlider()` as the FXMLLoader should instantiate it for you.